# Hodge star operator and heat propagator

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory, p-laplacian

I am currently studying the Laplacian on a Riemaniann Manifold: An introdcution to analysis on manifolds by S. Rosenberg. I am solving some of the exercises and one of  them (ex.3, ch 4.1 page 113) is to prove that:
$$
\star e^{-t\Delta^q}=e^{-t\Delta^{n-q}}\star
$$
Where $\star$ is the Hodge star operator and and $\Delta^p=\delta d+d\delta$ is the Hodge Laplacian. I am not able to solve this one and I am not really sure how to start. Also taking into acount the Hodge theorem ($Ker \Delta^p\cong H_{dR}^p$) and De rham's theorem $H_{dR}^n\cong H_{sing}^p$ does this property of the p Laplacian and Hodge star operator I am curious if there is any relationship with Poincare duality. Any help or refrences about this would be grealty appriciated.

Comment: Is it not the case that $\star$ and $\Delta$ commute?

Comment: I think this is correct. It probably follows from $\star \Delta^k=\Delta^{n-k}\star$

Comment: Indeed. :) .... And, to address your final query, if you represent cohomology classes by harmonic forms, then the Hodge star operator will give you Poincaré duality (in cohomology form).

Comment: Just to make sure, (because I do not know these proofs) the proofs of Hodge's theorem and De' rham theorem (that are needed to get Poicare duality this way)  do not need Poincare duality. Just to make sure this wont lead to a cyclic argument.

Comment: I already answered this, I think. But what is Poincaré duality to you?